# What's the meaning of the format parameter in SDL_AudioSpec?

Tags: audio, sdl

For playing audio with SDL, you have to provide an SDL_AudioSpec structure to open your audio device, there is a parameter here called "format". What is this? Is it related to the audio device or to the audio file?

Answer (score 2):

As is said by [documentation](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlaudiospec.html) (which you should read) format specifies Audio Data Format.

For example

```
AUDIO_U16MSB -> Unsigned 16-bit big-endian samples
```

or

```
AUDIO_U8 -> Unsigned 8-bit samples
```

Format describes what type of data is stored, char, unsigned char, short ,etc..., so the program can correctly parse it.

You can set your prefered format when you call [`SDL_OpenAudio()`](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlopenaudio.html). If the prefered format isn't available the settings are changed to hardware settings

Quote from docs:

*SDL_OpenAudio reads these fields from the desired SDL_AudioSpec structure pass to the function and attempts to find an audio configuration matching your desired. As mentioned above, if the obtained parameter is NULL then SDL with convert from your desired audio settings to the hardware settings as it plays.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did find the documentation, but it wasn't clear to me what it meant. Since it's a file property I tried to find it in the codecContext that I was getting from ffmpeg and for one file I found AV_SAMPLE_FMT_U8 which indeed matches the AUDIO_U8 setting in SDL, but another file tells me it's sample format is AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP. Any idea which SDL format matches with this? So far I've only gotten noise through the speakers ...

Comment: try AUDIO_S16 if on windows. Best would be to use  [SDL_mixer](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/)+ find a tutorial for it.